# How serialize count() from sql query to JSON

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-models

I have spatial query for postgresql (and postgis). I use raw() function. So I have something like this:

```
observations = Square.objects.raw('SELECT validation_birds_square.id AS id,
            validation_birds_square.identification,
            Count(validation_birds_checklist.position) AS total 
            FROM validation_birds_square  ...the rest of sql query...')
```

I use Square model which I defined in my models.py. Then I want serialize observations, so I make this:

```
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("json", observations), content_type='application/json')
```

But here is the problem. It serialize only properties of Square model, not **total** from sql query.

When I iterate over observations I can get that value:

```
for observation in observations:
    print(observation.total)
```

Is there any better way how to put **total** to serialized JSON than iterate over observations and serialize it manually to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a proper queryset, so there isn't much point in using the built-in serializers. Just create a list of dicts, and use JsonResponse to return it as JSON.

```
data = [{'id': o.id, 'identification': o.identification, 'total': o.total} for o in observations]
return JsonResponse(data)
```